# Symfony embedded formType in another formType for adding datas at the same time in two entities that have a ManyToOne relation

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, entity

I have a relation **ManyToOne** between two entities `Articles.php` and `Corrections.php`.

Look at this code, `Corrections.php` where my **FK constraint** is:

```
class Corrections
{
/**
     * @var \Articles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $article;
```

An *article* could have **many** *correction*, but a *correction* belong to only **one** *article*.

So, in my `Corrections.php`, I have the **foreign key** named `$article` refers to *article_id* in *MySQL database*.

Now I need to add a correction to an article in a form Type, but not only that.

This is the controller code for:

```
public function addCorrectionAction() {

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $correction= new Corrections;
        $form = $this->createForm(new CorrectionsType(), $correction);
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') | ($form->isValid()) ) {

                $form->bind($request);
                $correction= $form->getData();
                $em->persist($correction);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('indexArticles'));
        }

        else {
                return $this->render('Bundle:Folder:addCorrections.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
        }
    }
```

No problems here for now. This my buildForm, `CorrectionsType.php`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('text')
            ->add('articles', 'collection', array(
                                    'type' => new ArticlesType(),
                                    'allow_add' => true))
            ;
    }
```

And the twig view:

```
<form action="{{ path('addCorrection_process') }}" method="POST">
  {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <div class="row col-md-3">
      <input type="submit" value="Add correction and article" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In fact, I need to create a form which **allows a user to add an article and his correction at the same time**. Or here, when I display the `addCorrection method` with the form, *the field* **articles** is a **select** which **allow user to add a correction to an existing article**.

How can I proceed to have a form which **allow** user correctly **ADD a NEW correction and a NEW article at the time in the same form?** I need this form must **be consistent with my FK constraint too**, i-e when **I ADD a NEW correction with a NEW article** at the same time, the **FK** `$article` *(article_id)* have **the correct value refers** to the *correction_id*.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) official documentation page. So basically you create ArticleType and CorrectionType forms and connect the latter by collection field type.